# BAT file - replace multiple characters in filename

Tags: windows, file, syntax, cmd, batch-rename

Couldn't find an answer that wasn't very specific to someone else's problem.

I'd like to place a bat file in a directory and run it to achieve the following:

1. Replace all initial '-' (hyphen) with ' - ' (space-hyphen-space)
2. Replace any 3 char Month names (Jan,Feb,...Dec) with two-digit month number preceeded and followed by a hyphen ('Jan' = '-01-' , 'Mar' = '-03-')

So the following:

```
32432492-2015Jan23-2015Feb23.pdf 
32432492-2015Feb24-2015Mar24.pdf 
32432492-2015Mar25-2015Apr29.pdf
```

becomes:

```
32432492 - 2015-01-23 - 2015-02-23.pdf 
32432492 - 2015-02-24 - 2015-03-24.pdf 
32432492 - 2015-03-25 - 2015-04-29.pdf
```

I'd like the "rename" to only run once (instead of renaming all files over and over). It should do this for all files in current directory (except the current bat file of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "newname=%%a"
 FOR %%b IN ("Jan=-01-" "Feb=-02-" "Mar=-03-" ) DO SET "newname=!newname:%%~b!"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%b IN ("!newname!") DO SET "newname=%%b - %%c"
 IF /i NOT "!newname!"=="%%a" ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!newname!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I expect that you would have the sense to complete the month/number set in the form given.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

---

Revision

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "newname=%%a"
 FOR %%b IN ("Jan=/01/" "Feb=/02/" "Mar=/03/" ) DO SET "newname=!newname:%%~b!"
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=-" %%b IN ("!newname!") DO SET "newname=%%b - %%c - %%c"
 IF /i NOT "!newname!"=="%%a" ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!newname:/=-!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You said "Replace all initial '-' (hyphen) with ' - ' (space-hyphen-space)" which I took to mean "the initial hyphen in the name".

Comment: Is there no way to just use current working directory instead of setting the sourcedir? (THANKS BTW)

Comment: You could remove all references to `sourcedir` completely and that should process the entire current directory. I just use a specific directory which includes spaces for my testing. OR you could specify `sourcedir` as `.` which means "current directory"

Comment: great post. It almost works - the only problem it still has is it doesn't pick up the second hyphen and add spaces around it. From the example: `32432492-2015Jan23-2015Feb23.pdf ` becomes `32432492 - 2015-01-23-2015-02-23.pdf` instead of `32432492 - 2015-01-23 - 2015-02-23.pdf`